# problem with using <ol> with in <ul> in html and using css to change the result

Tags: html, css

For some reason that im not sure the  that is inside  the  about christopher paolini's books displays using bullet points instead of the lower-roman numerals. does anyone know whats wrong?

**Html**

```
<ol class="list">
    <li>Books

      <ul class="list">
        <li>Any thing by Mathew Riely</li>

        <li>Alex Rider series</li>

        <li>Christopher Paolini

          <ol class="list">
            <li>Eragon</li>

            <li>Eldest</li>

            <li>Brisingr</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>Music

      <ul class="list">
        <li>Muse</li>

        <li>Coldplay</li>

        <li>Red</li>

        <li>Radiohead</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>Films &amp; TV

      <ul class="list">
        <li>Inception</li>

        <li>Serenity</li>

        <li>Star Trek</li>

        <li>Surrogates</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

**css**

```
ul.list {
  list-style-image : url('images/bpr.png');
}

ol.list {
  list-style-type : lower-roman;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you trying it in Alex? I just tried your code in IE7, FF and Chrome and it works as you want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be working just fine for me. Are you sure that your CSS is being imported?

This works in safari's code snippet editor.

```
<style>
ul.list {
  list-style-image : url('images/bpr.png');
}

ol.list {
  list-style-type : lower-roman;
}
</style>

<ol class="list">
    <li>Books

      <ul class="list">
        <li>Any thing by Mathew Riely</li>

        <li>Alex Rider series</li>

        <li>Christopher Paolini

          <ol class="list">
            <li>Eragon</li>

            <li>Eldest</li>

            <li>Brisingr</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>Music

      <ul class="list">
        <li>Muse</li>

        <li>Coldplay</li>

        <li>Red</li>

        <li>Radiohead</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>Films &amp; TV

      <ul class="list">
        <li>Inception</li>

        <li>Serenity</li>

        <li>Star Trek</li>

        <li>Surrogates</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

Comment: i think its the list-style-image thats stuffing it up, without an image its fine but with is when im having the problem

Comment: this is only a section of the whole site, ive localised it down to the list-style-images css call tag. everything else works

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
ul.list { 
    list-style-type: none; 
}
ul.list li { 
    background : url('images/bpr.png') top left no-repeat transparent;
    padding-left: 10px; 
}
ol.list { 
    list-style-type : lower-roman; 
}
```

This will give you the image for the normal li items and a roman count for the ol list items.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:

```
<ol id="list">
<li>Books
  <ul>
    <li>Any thing by Mathew Riely</li>
    <li>Alex Rider series</li>
    <li>Christopher Paolini
      <ol>
        <li>Eragon</li>
        <li>Eldest</li>
        <li>Brisingr</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>Music
  <ul>
    <li>Muse</li>
    <li>Coldplay</li>
    <li>Red</li>
    <li>Radiohead</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>Films &amp; TV
  <ul>
    <li>Inception</li>
    <li>Serenity</li>
    <li>Star Trek</li>
    <li>Surrogates</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ol>
```

with the CSS as:

```
#list li
{
    list-style: lower-roman;
}

#list li li
{
    list-style: url('images/bpr.png');
}

#list li li li
{
    list-style: lower-roman;
}
```